# Zener diode as a switch

Tags: transistors, control, zener

I would like to use a Zener and a NPN transistor as a voltage switch to close a 12 VDC relay. My thought was 12 V zener to the base to turn on the transistor and close the relay when supply is above 12 V.

I have a very basic understanding of components and need a good starting point for discussion, prototyping and testing. I will reference and research any and all information given.

Comment: Zener diode can be used for this purpose. There's a few traps. External noises can cause unwanted state changes. And the same can happen if pulling the relay starts something which causes variations to the 12VDC. The circuit should have some hysteresis to prevent it. Relay itself is in several cases good for it because it holds with less voltage than what's needed for pulling. If you use the zener + transistor you maybe should add something to it to have the hysteresis. Schmitt Trigger is the fundamental idea to generate such hysteresis in a transistor circuit.

Comment: I did such a circuit with a pair of MOSFET. (You need two transistors to re-reverse the signal.) I noticed that a schmitt trigger is necessary to avoid grey zone of half on, half off states. (On top of helping with hysteresis. )

Comment: Have a look at this diagram... but read the comments before proceeding. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/697747/switch-transistor-with-zener-diode

Answer (score 2):

One problem with using a Zener in series with the base is that you're pretty much stuck with it switching at \$V_Z + V_{BE}\$.

By using it as a reference you can make the trip voltage adjustable.

Here's a circuit using a 5 V reference IC, the supply voltage is sampled through a voltage divider and compared to the reference, by adjusting the divider you can adjust the trip voltage. The output of the switch is fed back to provide some hysteresis, the relay will switch off at a slightly lower voltage than it switches on. This is to keep the relay from chattering right around the trip point. U1 could be replaced by a Zener, something like 5.1 V, the divider and R6 would probably need to be adjusted and Zeners are more temperature sensitive and their regulation is 'softer', so a reference IC is a better, albeit more expensive option. You can also replace Q3 and U1 with something like a [TL431](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl431.pdf), which can operate as a voltage comparator in much the same way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t mention if relay has own power supply or it is supplied from measured voltage.

Don’t forget to place a diode like 1n4007 across relay coil.

[image]

Comment: Here the relay will be on when there is excess current. Add a second transistor to re-reverse the signal.

Comment: Relay will be powered from reference voltage.  Reference voltage (battery) is 12.6 then 13 + when charging. Relay should be open when below charging voltage.

Comment: @DanielHart Put this information in the question, please.